# Is it possible to limit output bandwidth between eth0 and lo?

Tags: nginx, bandwidth, tc, loopback

I'm trying to limit the bandwidth between my eth0 output (nginx proxy) to my loopback inteface  (apache) by filtering on destination port.

```
Incoming Packet -> Eth0 -> 0.0.0.0:80 Nginx -> tc qdisc class/iptable mangle 2525port -> 127.0.0.1:2525 Apache
```

I don't know if it's even possible I'm just experimenting.

My rules are the followings :

```
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1:0 htb
tc class add dev eth0 parent 1:0 classid 1:10 htb rate 2mbps ceil 2mbps prio 0
tc filter add dev eth0 parent 1:0 prio 0 protocol ip handle 10 fw flowid 1:10

iptables -A OUTPUT -t mangle -p tcp --dport 2525 -j MARK --set-mark 10
```

I also tried to with FORWARD chain but its still the same.

Comment: You have an fundamental misunderstanding. Nginx will use the loopback interface to connect to Apache.

Comment: Yes I realised that and corrected my configuration, it's now working well on loopback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Andrew mentionned I was wrong by thinking that I should filter the eth0. As soon as I changed the configuration to loopback instead of eth0 everything worked fine.